# While actively using the internet over WiFi it cuts out and won't repair until restart

Tags: network, wifi

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro Ventura 13.0.1 and I'm using a Google Nest Wifi Mesh Router system (AC2200). About once per day usually when I am actively streaming something like Netflix or gaming, I will abruptly lose my connection to the internet. The WiFi router is inches from my computer and the signal always remains strong. But the only thing that seems to allow me to reconnect to the internet is restarting my laptop, not other fixes like toggling the Wi-Fi on/off on my laptop. But every time I restart, the problem is immediately resolved.

Is there something else I can fix so this stops happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are known issues with Wifi drop-outs in Ventura 13.0.1; and reports suggest that 13.1, which is expected soon, will fix them.

https://9to5mac.com/2022/12/12/macbook-wifi-issues-m1-m2-fix/